# Angular Js 'ng-router' or 'ui-router'

Tags: angularjs

I am building a Web app using AngularJS, and I am finding it difficult to choose between `ng-router` and `ui-router`.

It's kind of a big project and I can't make a wrong choice; could you help me take the right decision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngRoute is an angular core module which according to me is good for basic scenarios. On the other hand ui router is a contributed module which has overcome the issues faced by ngRoute. ui router becomes more powerful when it comes to handling complex nested views. So for a big project you should go for ui route as it may become complex after sometime to handle the views.

Answer (score 0):

According to [John Papa and his commonly accepted style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y270), "ui-router" is the router that you want to use:

### Why?:

> UI Router offers all the features of the Angular router plus a few
> additional ones including nested routes and states.
>
> The syntax is quite similar to the Angular router and is easy to migrate to UI router

Comment: I heard it's buggy ?